# err_too_many_redirects apenas em ambiente de produção

Tags: java, tomcat, redirecionamento

Tenho uma aplicação que faz o pagamento de alguns funcionários.

Na tela ele vem selecionado do mes atual, para não precisar selecionar, mas se tiver mtos dados em tela ele ao processar traz

> "A página de www.SISTEMA.com.br não está funcionando
>
> Redirecionamento em excesso por www.SISTEMA.com.br
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"

Pode ter haver com o estouro de memória?
Pois em meu ambiente teste funciona perfeitamente com a tela cheia, mas no ambiente do cliente não.

Comment: Conte mais sobre como você usa redirecionamento

Comment: Consegui resolver. Era uma propriedade do servidor que barrava o envio de mtos dados...

Comment: Sim, isso é uma espécie de trava de segurança, imagina se nós criarmos uma página que fica redirecionando uma para outra indefinidamente. O servidor travaria. Agora que encontrou a solução para o seu problema, publique uma resposta para ajudar alguém que possa sofrer com a mesma coisa!!

Comment: Realmente foi isso, mudei a segurança do meu servidor e funcionou. Bati a cabeça por praticamente um mês, mandei msg em vários fóruns, sem respostas. Resolvi ao entrar em contato com o suporte do servidor, devia ter feito de primeira.

Comment: Ótimo, mas responda sua pergunta com o que foi feito para ajudar o próximo :)

Comment: É uma configuração do servidor pago que utilizo, na tela de configuração deles! O problema não estava no sistema, e sim na configuração do servidor pago que hospeda meu sistema. Lá tem uma panel de configuração, onde eu desabilitei na segurança um ModSecurity. é especifico da hospedagem

Comment: estou pedindo que detalhe isso em uma resposta, não em comentário, eu não sei exatamente o que configurou em sua hospedagem, mas a idéia não é apenas resolver seu problema, mas se isso acontecer com alguém como ela vai resolver? Sua resposta pode ajudar outras pessoas, essa é idéia por trás do StackOverflow :)